# PHP: exif_imagetype explanation

Tags: php

http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

Can anyone give some more information about the rest extension types.

About these:

```
IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II (intel byte order)
IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM (motorola byte order)
IMAGETYPE_JPC
IMAGETYPE_JP2
IMAGETYPE_JPX
IMAGETYPE_JB2
IMAGETYPE_IFF
IMAGETYPE_WBMP
IMAGETYPE_XBM
```

From where do they all go?

It would be very good to know some numbers about % usage from overall uploaded images on some website if anyone knows as well.

Because currently i'm only using 1,2,3,6 exif numbers inside my uploader script.
I can't figure out now if someone was trying to upload different extension. :S

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) is somewhat obsolete, but is a lossless compressed format that was hobbled with not having a standard byte order, so there's Intel (little-endian) tiffs, and Motorola tiffs (big-endian).
[JB2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBIG) images are 1bit bitmaps used by fax machines.
[IFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_File_Format) comes from Amigas
[WBMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) are Windows bitmaps (the stereotypical .bmp file)
[XBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_BitMap) are X-windows monochrome bitmaps
[JPC/JP2/JPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000) are JPEG-2000 images

Comment: And which are the most used from them? Because i want to implement convert functions for the most used of them. Is there libraries of info about how to convert them to jpg for example?

Comment: You'd use imagick or GD, but I don't think GD supports anything but wbmp/xbm of those listed above. imagick might support more, but I don't use it much so don't know.